# How can I convert from anonymous type to and existing DTO

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a database with 3 tables and need to extract a resulting query based on 2 joins. I managed to interrogate the database and get the result, but the problem is that I need to convert it to an existing DTO that I have in order to be able to access its properties when I send it to my front application.

Here is the code of the interrogation

```
'var rez = _context.User.Where(x => x.Id ==id).Join'
               ' ('
                   ' _context.Rezervare,'
                   ' user => user.Id,'
                   ' rezervare => rezervare.userId, (user, rezervare) => new'
                    '{'
                     '   dataRezervare=rezervare.Data,'
                    '    numeUser = user.Nume,'
                   '     idUser = user.Id,'
                  '      idRezervare = rezervare.Id,'
                '        idProprietate = rezervare.proprietateId'
                 '   }'
               ' )'
               ' .Join'
               ' ('
                   ' _context.Proprietate,'
                   ' rezervare => rezervare.idProprietate,'
                   ' proprietate => proprietate.Id,'
                  '  (rezervare, proprietate) => new'
                   ' {'
                       ' User=rezervare.numeUser,'
                       ' idUser=rezervare.idUser,'
                      '  idRezervare=rezervare.idRezervare,'
                      '  idProprietate = proprietate.Id,'
                      '  numeProprietate = proprietate.Nume,'
                    '    judetProprietate=proprietate.Judet,'
                   '     orasProprietate= proprietate.Oras,'
                  '      stradaProprietate= proprietate.Strada,'
                 '       numarProprietate= proprietate.Numar,'
                '        dataRezervare=rezervare.dataRezervare'
               '     }'
              '  ).ToList();'
```

and here is the DTO that I want to convert this list into

```
 'public class GetRezervareUserDTO'
  '  {'
    '    public string user { get; set; }'
   '     public int idUser { get; set; }'
    '    public int idProprietate { get; set; }'
     '   public string numeProprietate { get; set; }'
        public string judetProprietate { get; set; }'
      '  public string orasProprietate { get; set; }'
       ' public string stradaProprietate { get; set; }'
        'public string numarProprietate { get; set; }'
    '    public DateTime dataRezervare { get; set; }'
    '}'
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you thought all those single-quotes were a good idea. Post the code properly, so we can read it comfortably.

Comment: For each user in your rez list variable create a new instance of your dto, populate the properties you need and you are done. You can also check out AutoMapper on how to make this easier.

Comment: You can also use the .Select() statement before .ToList(), to say something like -> .Select(x=> new UserDto() {// here populate the properties };).ToList()

Comment: Why you usedd ' in your code ?